# Alternating image on click Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, image

I am trying to alternate an image when the user clicks on it using jQuery

This is my jQuery code

```
$("#add").click(function(){
    var src = ($(this).attr("src") == "add.png")?"remove.png":"add.png";
    $("this").attr("src", src);
});
```

This is the HTML

```
<img id="add" src="add.png"></img>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quotes around `this`, remove them:

```
$("this").attr("src", src);
```

To:

```
$(this).attr("src", src);
```

Comment: Feel stupid for not realising that. Many thanks. Will mark as answer

Answer (score 0):

Use following:

```
$(function(){
        $("img#add").click(function(){
            var src = ($(this).attr("src") == "add.jpg")
                    ?"remove.jpg"
                    :"add.jpg";
            $(this).attr("src", src);
        });
    });
```

And:

```
<img id="add" src="add.jpg"/>
```